# Generic Templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I don't understand the answers to the following questions:

Write a C++ function find_elem that takes two iterators first and last of some
sequence of elements of type T and an object obj of type T. It returns the iterator to the first occurrence of obj in the range [first, last), or the iterator last if obj is not in the sequence.

This was the answer

```
template <typename It, typename T>
It find_elem(It first, It last, const T & obj) {
   while (first != last && (*first) != obj) // I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS LINE
   ++first;
   return first;
}
```

I dont understand the following line `while (first != last && (*first) != obj)`. Why is it `(*first != obj)` when the questions asks you to return the iterator with the first instance of `obj`. I also don't get the following line `++first` as in why you are incrementing the iterator `first`

Comment: if the compiler generates a type for that for example a string the template accepts a two string iterators and one string. if the first iterator is dereferenced and is equal to the string then you found the value if it is not then you move the first iterator sequentially and in order to be true the string must check if it is done checking all the character you dereference else were dont iterating the string

Answer (score 1):

The ++first is executed by the while loop.
I would write use { } here to make it clearer:

```
while (first!=last && (*first)!=obj) {
   ++first;
}
```

So, the while loop checks if (*first)==obj. If not, then it moves to the next element in the list using ++first, which increments the iterator. Then it ends either when first==last (meaning that we have gone through the entire list), or when (*first)==obj, meaning that we found what we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A **copy** of `first` is passed to the function. This means that the function can safely modify the variable by using it also to iterate the sequence.

It's just a concise alternative for the following code:

```
template <typename It, typename T>
It find_elem(It first, It last, const T & obj) {
   It iterator = first;
   while (iterator != last && (*iterator) != obj)
   ++iterator;
   return iterator;
}
```

---

By the way... "generic templates" sounds strange, because templates are always generic. I suppose template template parameters could be called "generic templates", though.

Comment: Thank you! I finally get it - so you pass by value because you don't want to modify the original right? But then why can't you pass by `const reference`?

Comment: @MoliswKikszsz: The copy you make is modifiable, but a const reference is not. You could not perform `++` on it.

Comment: Oh I see,yeah - thanks! One more thing, why do we return `first` or `iterator` if say `obj` was in `last`? That is another thing I don't understand. Also with the `while` statement are the conditions based on the fact that the outcome is not true - i.e `*first != obj`? Also why cant we pass the iterators by reference?

Comment: @MoliswKikszsz: `obj` cannot be in `last`. The C++ convention for ranges is that something like "last" is a special iterator to denote non-existence. For example, if you have a `std::vector` with 3 elements, then `begin()` would refer to the first element, `begin() + 1` to the second, `begin() + 2` to the third and `end()` to nothing.

Comment: `while` statements are a very basic concept, and you should really read a C++ textbook first. Iterators can be passed by reference. Why should that not be possible?

Comment: Oh I see, but the question said `"first & last are not necessarily the same as what is returned by a container’s begin() and end() methods!
The only thing we suppose is that the container is some sort of a sequence (e.g., vector, list, etc.) and that first is an iterator which points to an element which comes before the one pointed to by last."` Now I am confused :S - unless you can explain it clearly (you are good at explaining things btw)

Comment: @MoliswKikszsz: Well, "last" *can* also point to a valid element if you are passing a **sub-range**. For example, you could call the function like `std::vector<int> v(10); auto result = find_elem(v.begin() + 3, v.begin() + 6, 789);` to search the fourth, fifth and sixth element for the value "789". But even then "last" would mean "not found". `result` will point to the seventh element, but since you searched only the fourth, fifth and sixth, that really means just "not found where you searched for it".

Comment: Sorry I am still very very confused. I thought `last` was another iterator. What if the other iterator was called `twoIterator`?

Comment: @MoliswKikszsz: `last` *is* another iterator. What gives you the impression that it is not?